# How can I find out where a function is used?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to find out if and where a Postgres function is used in another Postgres function?

Compare it to the "Find All References" option in Visual Studio.

Comment: `pg_dump` to save the DB schema and then any text search tool.

Comment: The information is not stored in the database anywhere. So the only way is to search through the DDL. There are tools that can help you with that or grep the SQL dump as Abelisto suggested.